# taking javascript variable value into a html5

Tags: javascript, html

I can show in chrome console the data read from json file in a server using this js code:

```
    function leer2(){
      var invite_url = "initval";
      $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor",{format: "json"}).done( 
            function(person){
            invite_url = person.locale;
            console.log(invite_url);
        });
    };
```

and calling this js function by an event

```
    <button id="leer" onclick="leer2()">Leer BaseDat</button>
```

Let me do two questions: first, is it an unsecured way to read my json file like I'm doing ?, and second. How can I take the *invite_url* value into the /body tags and use it?

Comment: What do you mean "into the /body tags"?

Comment: ... and what do you mean by "use it"? (No offense OP but I'm a little amazed at the upvotes.)

Comment: Agree. Really need a better idea of what you are trying to do. Are you trying to store retrieved values from your JSON in specific places in your markup? If so, we need a better idea of the rest of your markup to advise you better.

Comment: I mean using that value to put in a table entry for example or convert  it in a string type etc.

Comment: @JoeCoolman well if you're getting the data successfully, then you'd just add it to the DOM somehow, depending on exactly what you want. Via jQuery you could for example update an element's content with `.text()` or `.html()` ... again, it'd help to see more specifics of your HTML etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `person.locale` value in the body of your HTML, you could create a div or a structure to hold the value returned and target it using the ID, like this:

```
function leer2(){
  var invite_url = "initval";
  $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor",{format: "json"}).done( 
        function(person){
        invite_url = person.locale;
        console.log(invite_url);

        // inserts the returned value into the div
        $("#invite_url_holder").text(invite_url);
    });
};

<div id="invite_url_holder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add HTML directly into a document using JQuery, simply use the following in your function:

```
$(element_you_want_to_add_html_to).text(the_inner_text);
```

or

```
$(element_you_want_to_add_html_to).html(the_inner_text);
```

Comment: I am testing the .html option (and it worked! with graph.facebook) but now with a json file copied from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) and coding with invite_url = person.employees[0].lastName but now it doesnt work. Console says _is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin_

Comment: nice! I've created a text file with json format and copied it to the WebContent in my Eclipse project and now the preview in localhost is ok in getting specific values from json array and showing it in the page dynamically . Then you can upload the html file to your server and everything gonna be ok. Thank you all.